# c# Console application blinking text message untill specific process complete

Tags: c#

I have following c# .net 2.0 code
i want to show a big ASCII text  Installing...
Want to show in Red And Green colors using 5 seconds delay.
Just want to stop message after P1 process exited
how to do this?

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process p1 = new Process();
        p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        p1.StartInfo.FileName = fullName;
        p1.Start(); 
        {           
        string textToEnter = @" Installing... ";

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(textToEnter))
        {
   foreach (ConsoleColor c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = c;
                Console.WriteLine(textToEnter2);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1 sec. deley
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
        }
        p1.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: This program is working and showing blinking text. But it is showing all colors and it not exited after my p1 process get exited.

Comment: if (p1.HasExited) break;

Comment: @HansPassant : Your a tony stark man...!!! Thanks alot . :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (p1.HasExited) break;
```

many thanks to
Hans Passant.

this is a right answer